# hypergeometric closed form for z=1/4,-1/3

Tags: hypergeometric-functions

There exist the linear identities for the 2f1 hypergeometric  function where z is either -1, 1, or 1/2 
using the quadratic transdormations it is easy to derive new identities in terms of gamma functions for z = -1/8,8/9 and 1/9

I have seen some identities with z=1/4 and z=-1/3 but there is no obvious transformation from the linear to the quadratic that yield these. 
So how do you derive them using the existing linear, quadratic transformation?

this problem i assure you is extremely difficult

Comment: This is too obscure. What identities do you mean? There is an infinite number of hypergeometric identities, derived by a wide variety of methods, so this post is completely vacuous.

Comment: more specifically this is the identity i want proven http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/05/05/

as you can see the z value is 1/4 

you can verify it by checking the differential equation or integral, but i would like to know what combination of the linear and quadratic transformations give this. 

Comment: Ah, OK. That clarifies things. Maybe you should edit the OP to include this...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible to derive these identities from quadratic transformations. However, it is possible to derive identities with $z=1/4$ from cubic transformations, though I don't know if the specific identity that the questioner asks about can be proved this way.

Here's an example. In the cubic transformation
\begin{multline*}{}_{2}F_{1}\left({{3a,1/3-a}\atop 2a+5/6}\Bigm |z\right)\\
=\left( 1-z \right) ^{-a}
 \left( 1+8z \right) ^{-2a}
{}_{2}F_{
1}\left({{a,a+1/2}\atop 2a+5/6}\Bigm |{\frac {27 z}{ \left(1-z
 \right)  \left( 1+8z \right) ^{2}}}\right)  \end{multline*}
 we can set $z=1/4$ to get 
\begin{align*}
  {}_{2}F_{1}\left({{3a,1/3-a}\atop 2a+5/6}\Bigm |1/4\right)&=
 \left( {\frac {4}{27}} \right) ^{a}
{}_{2}
F_{1}\left({{a,a+1/2}\atop 2a+5/6}\Bigm |1\right)\\
&=
\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3} \left( {\frac {4}{27}} \right) ^{a}{\frac {\Gamma  \left( 2a+5/6 \right) }{\Gamma  \left( 2/3 \right) 
\Gamma  \left( a+5/6 \right) \Gamma  \left( a+1/3 \right) }}.
\end{align*}